# Swampy.1.1 with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading the book [Think Python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/) by Allen Downey. For chapter 4, one has to use a suite of modules called [Swampy](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/). I have downloaded and installed it.

The problem is that the modules were written in Python 2 and I have Python 3 (in Windows 7 RC1). When I ran the TurtleWorld module from Swampy, I got error messages about the print and exec statements, which are now functions in Python 3. I fixed those errors by including parentheses with print and exec in the code of the GUI and World modules. I also got an error that the Tkinter module could not be found. It turned out that in Python 3, the module name is spelled with a lower case t.

The third error is more difficult: ImportError: No module named tkFont.

Does anyone have any idea, please? Thank you.

Comment: I figured out tkFont should be replaced by tkinter.font. Then I had to change .iteritems() to .items() and TurtleWorld's gui finally showed. But now I ran into run-time errors: the butto that makes the turtle reverse did not work, and that ws because it is controlled by the 'apply()' built-in function, which is no longer supported by Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many important third-party libraries have not yet been rewritten for Python 3; you'll have to stick to Python 2.x for now. There is no way around it. As it says on the [official Python download page](http://www.python.org/download/),

> If you don't know which version to
>   use, start with Python 2.6.4; more
>   existing third party software is
>   compatible with Python 2 than Python 3
>   right now.

Comment: This would be the simplest. Thanks. I will give the conversion tool suggested by Stephen Doyle a try first.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like tkinter is finally catching up with Python 3 -  tkFont has become tkinter.font

http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#       font_ex.py
#       

import tkinter

top = tkinter.Tk()

butt01 = tkinter.Button(top, text="Hello World", font=('Helvetica', 24,))

custom_font_serif = ('Times', 24, 'bold')
butt02 = tkinter.Button(top, text="Hello World", font=custom_font_serif)

custom_font_sans = ('Helvetica', 36, 'italic')
butt03 = tkinter.Button(top, text="Hello World", font=custom_font_sans)

butt01.pack()
butt02.pack()
butt03.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

FOR MAC USERS: I'm a Python newbie and came across the exact same problem. I'm writing this so others don't waste several hours trying to figure this out. Here's what you do:

- Do NOT install Python 3 for the above reasons, i.e. to avoid having to change all the Swampy code. Instead, download the latest version of Python 2 (I used 2.7.5).
- Then download the Swampy-2.1.1.tar.gz file from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/swampy/2.1.1. Extract this file by double-clicking on it in your Downloads folder.
- Open the resulting folder, Swampy 2.1.1. You should see several items, including the folder, swampy.
- Here's the key step: Drag this folder to the last one in this path: Macintosh HD/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages. TO REPEAT: drag the folder "swampy" and drop it into the "site-packages" folder.
- Once you do that, fire up Python in the terminal and type "import swampy.TurtleWorld." If you see the chevrons (>>>) and you don't see an error message, you're good to continue the lessons.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conversion tool for converting Python 2 code to work with Python 3: http://svn.python.org/view/sandbox/trunk/2to3/

Not sure how this extends to 3rd party libraries but it might be worth passing this over the swampy code.